# Does the return statement cause the execution to jump out from the currently executed function?

Tags: c++

```
bool accept3()
{
    int tries = 1;
    while (tries<4) {
        cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n"; // write question
        char answer = 0;
        cin >> answer; // read answer
        switch (answer) {
            case 'y':
                return true;
            case 'n':
                return false;
            default:
                cout << "Sorry, I don't understand that.\n";
                ++tries; // increment
        }
    }
    cout << "I'll take that for a no.\n";
    return false;
}
```

Does the return statement cause the execution to jump out from the currently executed function (in this case accept3()) and after it is returned, the code below it will not run, right?

Comment: Indentation is a good start to understand any code. Learning how to use a debugger and how to step through code line by line is also good.

Comment: You do expect `return` not to exit the function?

Comment: [C++ keywords: break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/break).

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between break/continue/return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement will cause the execution jump out from the currently executed function (in this case `accept3()`), so the loop inside the function is also jumped out.

Answer (score 4):

The `return` statement does not care if you are in the middle of a loop or not. When you `return` something, you immediately leave the execution of that function.

Answer (score 1):

When the input stored in `answer` is `y` the first case of the switch statement gets entered, containing a `return true;`, which returns from the function `accept3()`, thus also leaving the `while`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because `return` statement terminates the current function and returns the result of the expression to the caller. While loop condition in this case does not matter.